# Complicated separation from column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like specific separations of values within my column to display percentages. I would like the **first  'word' that is separated by '-'** **and its #T value. ex. (12T)** Essentially I would be grouping the Type ***if the first word matches***, **as well as its #T** (ex.12T, 50T etc)  Some of the #T values look like this: ***6.4T*** , and some of the 'first' words look like: **AY14.5**

***UPDATED***

```
There are        2  unique counts    of   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T
                 2  unique counts    of   Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T
                 1  unique count(s)  of   Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T
                 2  unique counts    of   Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0
                 2  unique counts    of   AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A
```

**Data:**

```
Type

Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A    
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E    
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C    
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A    
Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A  
Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0
Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0       
AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A
AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A
```

**Desired:**

```
Type                                    Percent

Hello    12T                        22.2%
Hello    50T                        22.2%
Happy    90T                        11.1%
Kind     14T                        22.2%
AY14.5   6.4T                       22.2%
```

**Doing:**

```
df=df.assign(Type=df.Type.str.split('_').str[0]) df2= 
(df['Type'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).to_frame('%') 
print(df2.rename_axis(index='Type'))
```

However, my ***output is showing the full Type (name)***, and it is ***excluding cases where the '_' comes
before the #T  (ex. 12T)***

```
Type     
                         
Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T
```

Any suggestion is appreciated, I am still troubleshooting.

***UPDATED***

**Desired:**

```
Type                                    Percent

Hello    12T                        22.2%
Hello    50T                        22.2%
Happy    90T                        11.1%
Kind     14T                        22.2%
AY14.5   6.4T                       22.2%
```

Comment: I would suggest you create a new column, using a regex for XXT (XX is integer), to save the different outputs, and group on it to get the percentages

Comment: ok @IoaTzimas I will try this- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

def extract_value(s):
    regex = re.search(r'(^.+?)-.+?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?T)', s)
    if regex:
        first_word = regex.group(1)
        code = regex.group(2)
        return f'{first_word} {code}'
    return s

df = pd.DataFrame([['Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A'],
                   ['Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E'],
                   ['Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C'],
                   ['Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A'],
                   ['Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A'],
                   ['Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0'],
                   ['Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0'],
                   ['AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A'],
                   ['AY14.5-fyy-FY-R770-256G-6.4T-R1-v.A']])

df.columns = ['Type']
df['Type'] = df['Type'].apply(lambda x: extract_value(x))
df2 = (df['Type'].value_counts(normalize=True)*100).to_frame('%')
print(df2.rename_axis(index='Type').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
          Type          %
0  AY14.5 6.4T  22.222222
1     Kind 14T  22.222222
2    Hello 50T  22.222222
3    Hello 12T  22.222222
4    Happy 90T  11.111111
```

Comment: Hello @David it is giving me: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 1 elements

Comment: Could you please post the data sample that generates this error?

Comment: I have updated my code and output accordingly.

Comment: Ok it is saying: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' - I will look this up

Comment: This means that the regex was not matched. (At least ) one of your rows does not correspond to the pattern described so far.

Comment: ok is there a way to override it and just proceed?

Comment: Sure. I have amended the code so that rows that do not match the pattern will be ignored. Informally, the regex is looking for all characters up to (but excluding) the first hyphen, and then for a number (integer or decimal) followed by T.

Comment: I see @David, what does it do to the rows that do not match? will it discard them? if so is there a way to still show the ones that are 'left over'?

Comment: ok it is now saying: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object - do I need to convert the Type col to string?

Comment: You mean showing the entire row instead of the first word only when the row does not match the pattern?

Comment: yes - basically I am wondering if the un matched ones will just not show up  -  also for the Type error , should i convert the Type column to string?

Comment: I have amended the code to return the full row if the regex pattern is not matched. As for the error, I would need to see the row that causes it.

Comment: ok thank you- I am thinking I can just convert to string though right? wouldn't this solve?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to say because I don't know where the error comes from. The output returned by the function `extract_value()` (whether regex or full row) is always a string.

Comment: This works- I troubleshot this and see it is due a NULL within my column

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Type': {0: 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.A',
  1: 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-12T_TYPE-v.E',
  2: 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.C',
  3: 'Hello-HEL-HE-A6123-123A-50T_TYPE-v.A',
  4: 'Happy-HAP-HA-R650-570A-90T_version-v.A',
  5: 'Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0',
  6: 'Kind-KIN-KI-T490-NET_14T-A.0'}})  

df.Type = df.Type.str.split('-').str[0] + ' ' + df.Type.str.extract('(\d+T)')
(df.groupby('Type').size() / len(df) * 100).to_frame('Percent').reset_index()
```

Output

```
        Type    Percent
0   Hello 12T   28.571429
1   Hello 14T   28.571429
2   Hello 50T   28.571429
3   Hello 90T   14.285714
```

Comment: Thank you- for some reason alot of my data is not showing up - let me re check (it works for some, not for all)